# Play framework - query parameter binding with custom class

Tags: java, playframework, binding, query-string

I use Play framework and I want to provide support for queries like this:

```
myroute?param=blablabla&bbox=57.121,1.778,58.144,3.798
```

and to map these parameters using Java class:

```
public class MyQuery {
    private String param;
    private BBox bbox;

    // + getters and setters
}
```

where **BBox** will be:

```
public class BBox {
    private Double minLat;
    private Double minLon;
    private Double maxLat;
    private Double maxLon;

    // + getters and setters
}
```

and later in my controller to call:

```
Form<MyQuery> form = Form.form(MyQuery.class).bindFromRequest();
if (!form.hasErrors()) {
   MyQuery q = form.get();
   q.getBBox().getMinLat();
   q.getBBox().getMinLon();

   // ...
}
```

At the moment I have no BBox class and I use String + @ValidateWith annotation, but this approach looks ugly for me.

Is there a solution (preferable with Form) that allows to keep validation, parsing and assigning values all together in one place (one class)?

Comment: I think you want a custom data binder: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/JavaForms#Register-a-custom-DataBinder

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for.